# How can I use 2 DB contexts in 1 method? C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I'm writing a method to save invoices for each member, invoice and member are different entities with different repositories. How can I make use of both of these contexts? Should I dispose the member repository and when?

```
 public RedirectToRouteResult CalculateAllInvoices()
        {
            var amount = _memberRepository.GetAll().Count();

            for (int i = 1; i<amount; i++)
            {

                Member m = _memberRepository.GetSingle(i);


                CalculateInvoice(m);

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Overview");
        }

        private void CalculateInvoice(Member member)
        {
            double invoicePrice = 0.0;
            ICollection<Sport> sports = member.Sports;

            foreach(Sport s in sports){
               invoicePrice =+ s.Price;
            }

            Invoice i = new Invoice { SendDate = DateTime.Now, Status = false, Member = member, Price = invoicePrice };

           _memberRepository.Dispose();
            _InvoiceRepository.Add(i);
            _InvoiceRepository.Save();
        }
```

Comment: retrieving all the members, and calculating the count to loop over all the members who you retrieve separately is very bad thing to do, Just loop over all the members with a foreach on the GetAll

Comment: Also, using multiple contexts in the same method is no reason for errors. Are you getting errors?